# C# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem with code in c#. Sorry im newbie. I want import and export data to database. When I import *.xlsx i have comunique:

> Exception type "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException" ASP Export Import.dll, but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The string "EmployeeData $" is not a valid name

Deafult.aspx.cs

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ASPExportImport
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateData();
                lblMessage.Text = "Current Database Data!";
            }
        }
        private void PopulateData()
        {
            using (MuDatabaseEntities dc = new MuDatabaseEntities())
            {
                gvData.DataSource = dc.EmployeeMaster.ToList();
                gvData.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" ||
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                try
                {
                    string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ImportDocument"), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(fileName);

                    string conString = "";
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    if (ext.ToLower() == ".xls")
                    {
                        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\""; ;
                    }
                    else if (ext.ToLower() == ".xlsx")
                    {
                        conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                    }

                    string query = "Select [EmployeeID],[CompanyName], [ContactName],[ContactTitle],[EmployeeAdress],[PostalCode] from [EmployeeData$]";
                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                    }
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    da.Dispose();
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();

                    // Import to Database
                    using (MuDatabaseEntities dc = new MuDatabaseEntities())
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            string empID = dr["EmployeeID"].ToString();
                            var v = dc.EmployeeMaster.Where(a => a.EmployeeID.Equals(empID)).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (v != null)
                            {
                                // Update here
                                v.CompanyName = dr["CompanyName"].ToString();
                                v.ContactName = dr["ContactName"].ToString();
                                v.ContactTitle = dr["ContactTitle"].ToString();
                                v.EmployeeAdress = dr["EmployeeAdress"].ToString();
                                v.PostalCode = dr["PostalCode"].ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Insert
                                dc.EmployeeMaster.Add(new EmployeeMaster
                                {
                                    EmployeeID = dr["EmployeeID"].ToString(),
                                    CompanyName = dr["CompanyName"].ToString(),
                                    ContactName = dr["ContactName"].ToString(),
                                    ContactTitle = dr["ContactTitle"].ToString(),
                                    EmployeeAdress = dr["EmployeeAdress"].ToString(),
                                    PostalCode = dr["PostalCode"].ToString()
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        dc.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    PopulateData();
                    lblMessage.Text = "Successfully data import done!";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (MuDatabaseEntities dc = new MuDatabaseEntities())
            {
                List<EmployeeMaster> emList = dc.EmployeeMaster.ToList();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                if (emList.Count > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ImportDocument"), DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".xlsx");
                    string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'";
                    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                    {
                        string strCreateTab = "Create table EmployeeData (" +
                            " [Employee ID] varchar(50), " +
                            " [Company Name] varchar(200), " +
                            " [Contact Name] varchar(200), " +
                            " [Contact Title] varchar(200), " +
                            " [Employee Address] varchar(200), " +
                            " [Postal Code] varchar(50))";
                        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                        }

                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strCreateTab, con);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        string strInsert = "Insert into EmployeeData([Employee ID],[Company Name]," +
                            " [Contact Name], [Contact Title], [Employee Address], [Postal Code]" +
                            ") values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        OleDbCommand cmdIns = new OleDbCommand(strInsert, con);
                        cmdIns.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);
                        cmdIns.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 200);
                        cmdIns.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 200);
                        cmdIns.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 200);
                        cmdIns.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 200);
                        cmdIns.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 50);

                        foreach (var i in emList)
                        {
                            cmdIns.Parameters[0].Value = i.EmployeeID;
                            cmdIns.Parameters[1].Value = i.CompanyName;
                            cmdIns.Parameters[2].Value = i.ContactName;
                            cmdIns.Parameters[3].Value = i.ContactTitle;
                            cmdIns.Parameters[4].Value = i.EmployeeAdress;
                            cmdIns.Parameters[5].Value = i.PostalCode;

                            cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    // Create Downloadable file
                    byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
                    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(content);
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=EmployeeData.xlsx");
                    Context.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Deafult.aspx

```html
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASPExportImport._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

 
        <h3>Import / Export database data from/to Excel.</h3>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Select File : </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnImport" runat="server" Text="Import Data" OnClick="btnImport_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server"  Font-Bold="true" />
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <div style="padding:10px">
                        Data not found!
                    </div>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmployeeID" DataField="EmployeeID" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CompanyName" DataField="CompanyName" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ContactName" DataField="ContactName" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ContactTitle" DataField="ContactTitle" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="EmployeeAddress" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PostalCode" DataField="PostalCode" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export Data" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Example file to import:
http://185.5.99.98/EmployeeData.xlsx

FullProject:
http://185.5.99.98/ASPExportImport.zip

Thx for all answer....

Comment: Restating the obvious, the error message says 'The string "EmployeeData $" is not a valid name.'  Which it isn't.

Comment: is the space in the name `"EmployeeData $"` valid..? what happens when you use the debugger to step through the code..? have you tried that first..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string query = "Select [EmployeeID],[CompanyName], [ContactName],[ContactTitle],[EmployeeAdress],[PostalCode] from [EmployeeData$]";
```

It appears that you are trying to pull data from an invalid table name.  Is the $ sign intentional in the above listed code snippet?

Presuming you are attempting to pull data from table name EmployeeData, and not EmployeeData$, change the SQL query to use:

```
...FROM [EmployeeData]
```

***Edit***
I downloaded the sample files, and manually cut them into a new project to test your routine.  It appears that the code itself works just fine.  I was able access the excel spreadsheet without any problems.  Please check your excel spreadsheet for typos.  I noticed that in your sample spreadsheet there were quite a few errors which would cause the query to crash.  Specifically, verify that the tab in your spreadsheet is named EmployeeData.  In addition, verify all column header spellings.

The following code snippet ran without any issues, and should encompass the core functionality of reading the excel spreadsheet.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                string fileName = @"Fully Justified path\testbook.xlsx";
                string ext = ".xlsx";
                string conString = "";
                if (ext.ToLower() == ".xls")
                {
                    conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\""; ;
                }
                else if (ext.ToLower() == ".xlsx")
                {
                    conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }

                string query = "Select [EmployeeID],[CompanyName], [ContactName],[ContactTitle],[EmployeeAdress],[PostalCode] from [EmployeeData$]";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                da.Dispose();
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    string empID = dr["EmployeeID"].ToString();

                    // Update here
                    string empID1 = dr["CompanyName"].ToString();
                    string empID2 = dr["ContactName"].ToString();
                    string empID3 = dr["ContactTitle"].ToString();
                    string empID4 = dr["EmployeeAdress"].ToString();
                    string empID5 = dr["PostalCode"].ToString();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To use an Excel Worksheet as a tablename you need to add the $ at the end of the worksheet name.

Comment: I did not realize that.  So, given that the error is with the [EmployeeData$] name, either the space in the original posts exception ("EmployeeData $") is in fact the problem, or possibly the tab in the spreadsheet is named improperly?

Comment: The error seems to be raised in the Import code (btnImport_Click) and there the table is written without a space, but the error message has a space. Something is not quite clear here.

Comment: I agree. Code seems to run fine, given no typos in the excel spreadsheet.  Knowing exactly what line throws the error would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends thx for answer...
I search in html:

```html
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="EmployeeAddress" />
```

must be

```html
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="EmployeeAdress" />
```

I know Adress is wrong word ;) sorry for my english ;)

And in worksheet is

> Emloyee ID

must be

> Employe ID

And works very well ;) Thanks all.